# lexmark e230 can't print on 12.04 and later

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, printing, lexmark

The printer will print a test page and then, anything I give it results in garbage spitting out. Every page gets a bit of it on the top.

```
"PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PCLXL
                                                           ) HP-PCL XL;1;1; Comment Copyright Artifex Software"
```

This is what will come out on the first page of many. The rest just get a bit random gibberish on the top.

Here is a listing of the debugging log in pastebin http://pastebin.com/cLRrpMEj

I have also tried replacing pxlmono and choosing other drivers like ljet4. It gave a tad better results but the resulting pages still have some garbage on them.

Adding a pastebin listing of the cupsd.conf file: http://pastebin.com/qunuUKkA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have finally fixed my problem. I was having issues like those described on bug #872483. What worked for me was doing:

> lpadmin -p printer_name -o usb-no-reattach-default=true

where printer is what is listed by the **lpstat -p** command.

In my case:

> printer Lexmark-E230 is idle. enabled since Wed 19 Jun 2013 03:35:49
>   PM EEST  Sending data to printer.

so the above command becomes:

> lpadmin -p Lexmark-E230 -o usb-no-reattach-default=true

Turned the printer off, waited a bit, turned it back on and the tried running some print jobs. It stopped printing gibberish after completing the first print job.

Also, make sure to select a maximum resolution of 600x600 dpi. This is the maximum this printer can do despite what marketing may want you to believe.